# Have the same symbol for the items of a list when nested in another list or enumeration

Tags: enumerate, itemize, scrbook

I'm writing a document based on the class `scrbook` (but I believe my question applies to many other classes).

There is a little thing with enumerations and list that bothers me.

If I have a list nested in another list, outer items have a dot as symbol and inner items have a dash:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Outer element
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Inner element
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Which is rendered in:

```
* Outer element
  - Inner element
```

Now, if I have a list nested into an enumeration, outer items are numbered and inner items have a dot:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Outer element
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Inner element
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
```

Which is rendered in:

```
1. Outer element
   * Inner element
```

Since the list items in the enumeration are 2nd level items, I would expect them to have the same symbol than 2nd level items nested into another list.

Instead, the counter for nested enumerations and lists are kept separated and the list nested into the enumeration counts as 1st level list.

In practice, we have a `*` instead of a `-`.

I've spent a good half an hour looking for solutions without finding any (probably I haven't found the right set of keywords to get anywhere) and then I played a little with `\def\labelitemi{*}` and `\def\labelitemii{-}` but with no luck.

I saw that the space above the editor got populated with links after I described the issue, but none of them seems to be related.

I was wondering if there are known solutions to this problem or if anyone could help with a workaround. I believe a way of doing it would be to sum the counters for list and enumeration levels and use the resulting number to choose the `\labelitem*`, but I don't know from where to start.

Thanks in advance for any pointer or help!

---

I just realised that I could specify `--` as a parameter of my inner `\item`:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Outer element
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[--] Inner element
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
```

Which is rendered in:

```
1. Outer element
   - Inner element
```

Even though it produces the expected result, it does feel like a permanent solution as every time I have nested lists and enumerations I have to remember to use this trick. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `\makeatletter\let\@enumdepth\@itemdepth\makeatother` probably does what you want

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle, it does what I was looking for!
Basically overwrites the depth of nested enumerations with the depth of nested lists?
I wonder whether I'm causing problems by doing so when in the opposite scenario: enumeration inside a list? Will figure out...

Comment: it makes both environments use the same depth counter, so an enumerate in an itemize would similarly use depth two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\makeatletter
\let\@enumdepth\@itemdepth
\makeatother
```

This makes the counters the same, so incrementing one also increments the other, rather than just setting one counter to the value of another.

So after this, an enumerate in an itemize will use level 2 settings, as will an itemize in an enumerate.